# Help identifying a brick

Tags: part-identification

Found this part a Lego event and would like to get some but can’t seem to locate.  I believe it’s from a technic set.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is a [CATAPULT ARM 1X4](https://brickset.com/parts/design-88289) (88289) in [black](https://brickset.com/sets/containing-part-6225386)

Comment: Alternative name is [Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Pin Hole and Bucket (Catapult)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=88289) (Bricklink)